# Visual Studio 2005: How to speed up builds when a VSMDI is open?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

Using Visual Studio 2005, if I open tests in a VSMDI and try running tests, it sometimes re-builds projects. However, these builds go extremely slow. The CPU is 99% idle and the output window shows VS clunking along compiling things. Is there any way to fix this? It makes no sense. Upgrading isn't necessarily a viable option for those of us with shared legacy code to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried upgrading to SP1?  I don't know of any specific issues in this area but this would be the first change I tried to make.